# PHP - How I can get innerHTML on an element?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am novice in PHP. I have javascript functions for adding , removing and moving favorites (DOM Manipulation only).
When I refresh the page this favorites are cleared.
I need:

1.Get innerHTML on current (DOM manipulated) favorites DIV element (where favorites are).

2.Store the HTML in PHP varable (i need 'php' varable cuz i will insert the value in DB).

**Favorite DIV with one favorite created :**

```
<div id="favorites">
    <div id="1" class="favorite">
       <sub class="minID">Id 1</sub>
       <a href="http://www.zamunda.net">Zamunda.NET</a>
       <span onclick="movefavorite(1)">
          <img class="move" src="icon/move.png" title="Move">
       </span>
       <span onclick="removefavorite(1)">
           <img class="delete" src="icon/del.png" title="Delete">
       </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: AJAX, or maybe a cookie, if it's small enough. You'll also need to store the info passed to the php via AJAX in a database

Comment: Indeed, you should save your favorite in cookie, assuming it does not requiere a lot of space. cookie information is sent from the client to the server at each request, so you can add cookie on the client side (with javascript) and read the cookie content on the PHP server side to build correct HTML content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

js:

```
var v = document.getElementsByClassName('minID')[0].innerHTML; // select whatever
$.cookie("something", v, { expires: 5 }); // set cookie
```

php:

```
<?php
     echo $_COOKIE['something'];
     /* ... */
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do one of the following, depending on what you're really trying to accomplish.

1. Do an ajax post to your PHP code that contains the information required to save the favorite entries (i.e. just the ID, URL and name, not the actual HTML).
2. Maintain a few hidden form fields that hold the information required to save the favorite entries. This will give you access to the data from PHP with the form is submitted (assuming a form is involved).

Note that I don't think what you really want is to get the innerHTML of elements from your PHP code. You probably want to find a way to represent that information in a way that can more easily be sent to your server-side code.